# Tunneling on Linux through VPN on windows host for yum

Tags: ssh, centos6, yum, tunnel

I need to upgrade and install some yum packages on remote server without internet access that's only accessible with a VPN client on a Windows host. Once this VPN connection is established the Windows host loses internet access, but can still access local servers. Both Linux servers are CentOS 6.

[local linux server 192.168.0.10] <- [windows host] -> [remote server 10.10.0.20]

I set up two putty sessions on the windows host. 
For the local server session I've added a local tunnel on port 2201 to 192.168.0.10:22
For the remote server session I've added a remote tunnel on port 2202 to localhost:2201
Using this setup I can connect with SSH from remote server to local server with `ssh localhost -p 2202`

Now, I've tried numerous ways to for setting up additional tunnels and what not to allow yum to use this connection, but no luck so far.
I found many posts describing how to use `proxy=socks5h://localhost:port` in yum.conf, but my version of yum doesn't appear to support socks5h.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? If so, what's the missing piece of my puzzle?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would compiling the sources directly on the host be an option ? That's usually a good and easy option when being disconnected from the internet.

Comment: Instead of compiling the sources, it would be much easier to set up a local mirror of the CentOS repo and point yum to it. It's fairly easy - just look up the manpage for "createrepo"

Comment: It started with having to install virtualbox rpm on the remote machine, then it kind of snowballed with dependencies from there, and older package versions no longer available. It lacks many of the compiler tools,  so that will not work unfortunately. I can't set up local mirror at remote site, but perhaps I can set it up on local server and add extra tunnels to there and somehow make it work. I'll try this, thanks.